# Do I have to synchronize on a List that is read by a stream?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

if I have a Thread sensitive List I go usually like this while iterating over it:

```
    List list = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList());
...
synchronized(list) {
    Iterator i = list.iterator(); // Must be in synchronized block
    while (i.hasNext())
        foo(i.next());   
}
```

I wonder if I use list.stream() and do then some operations over the stream like filter etc., if I also have to put the list into a synchronize block or does the stream makes a copy of the list?

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Stream operations use `spliterator()` method internally.

Here is the `spliterator()` method from `ArrayList`:

```
    public Spliterator<E> spliterator() {
        checkForComodification();
        return new ArrayListSpliterator<E>(ArrayList.this, offset,
                                           offset + this.size, this.modCount);
    }
```

It checks for comodification, so it looks like `stream()` operations have to be inside synchronized blocks in your case.

Also, `spliterator()` of `SynchronizedCollection` (in `Collections`) has comment

```
    public Spliterator<E> spliterator() {
        return c.spliterator(); // Must be manually synched by user!
    }
```

which is analogous to the comment in `iterator()`:

```
    public Iterator<E> iterator() {
        return c.iterator(); // Must be manually synched by user!
    }
```

which shows the same: synchronization is needed around `stream()` operations (at least, if `iterator()` requires such a synchronization).

And the most convincing: `stream()` method from `SynchronizedCollection`:

```
    public Stream<E> stream() {
        return c.stream(); // Must be manually synched by user!
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

**Yes, you have to synchronize access to the list** when using streams in the same way you would do without streams. Synchronization should be taken care of by a user.

A stream by itself doesn't guarantee to create any copy of the original *sequence*. It *can* make a copy during some intermediate computations (e.g. `sort`), but you should not rely on that. And doing this for each usage of a stream would be a waste of resources since streams [are not reusable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html).

If a user wants a stream to operate over a copy, they have to manually create a copy or use `CopyOnWriteArrayList` instead of `ArrayList`, for example.

Moreover, keep in mind that [streams are lazy](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html). The underlying sequence is not accessed until a *terminal operation* (e.g. `collect`, `forEach`) is executed.

Answer (score 0):

A stream can be seen as a "view" on the original data. This means: it is part of their nature to avoid making copies.

Only operations like sorting require creating a copy of the input. Thus: when your input can be changed by another thread - then you need to protect against that.